# find the process which is listening on a specific port

Tags: networking, tcp, netstat

I want to find some processes which are running on a specified port
for example `80`

I ran

```
fuser 80/tcp
```

and got nothing

and then

```
netstat -tulpn|grep "80\|PID"
```

and got

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      -
```

the PID is `-`

so what does `-` mean?
thanks!

Comment: Do you run these commands as root?

Comment: no, ah, I ran it now as root, it shows results, thanks

Comment: @mpy Please post this as an answer (maybe extend it and explain why you need to be root etc.)

Comment: @slhck: You gave quite a tough nut to crack *why* you need to be root... `;)`

Comment: @mpy Haha, well that's a great answer for sure. I just thought that "You have to be root" wouldn't pass the quality filter :)

Comment: @misteryes: Please consider to accept my answer as a solution -- thanks.

Answer (score 3):

*The short answer is:* You need to be `root` in order to see all bindings.

*A little bit longer:*

The manpage of netstat gives a hint that is not necessary in all cases:

> **PID/Program name**
>          Slash-separated  pair  of  the  process  id (PID) and process name of the process that owns the socket.  `--program` causes this
>   column to be
>          included.  You will also need superuser privileges to see this information on sockets you don't own.

So, as a normal user you only see which process listens to a port, if you own it:

```
$ netcat -l -p 1234 &
$ netstat -tulpn
[...]
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1234            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8044/netcat     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -    
[...]
```

You see "your" netcat process, but not who is listening to e.g. port 22.

I have a feeling, that the reason for that is, that you can't acces `/proc/[PID]/fd` for not-owned processes. There you find the file descriptors process `[PID]` has currently opened and in Un*x (nearly) everything is a file... and so are sockets.

In my example `sshd`, pid 3934, listens to port 22 (surprise-surprise):

```
$ whoami
user
$ ls -l /proc/3934/fd
/bin/ls: cannot open directory /proc/3934/fd: Permission denied
$ sudo ls -l /proc/3934/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Apr 24 16:33 0 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Apr 24 16:33 1 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Apr 24 16:33 2 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Apr 24 16:33 3 -> socket:[10481]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Apr 24 16:33 4 -> socket:[10483]
```

(The second socket is bond to the IPv6 adress which I omitted in my netstat output.)